# Search By Google Place Autocomplete and get the distance from google matrix API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-place-report

I developed the code for our website that a user can autocomplete the location field using google places API and calculate distance from google matrix API using the lat-long.

1- My Code for autocomplete the location

```
<script>
var frm_ggl_dd = 1;
function initMap() {    
var options = {
    /*types: ['(cities)'],
    regions:['(locality,sublocality,postal_code)'],*/
    componentRestrictions: {country: "in"}
};


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 28.6315, lng: 77.2167},
  zoom: 13
});
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));

var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
//map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
});

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  frm_ggl_dd = 1;
  infowindow.close();
  marker.setVisible(false);
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }

  // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
  }

  /*setting hidden field value so that have idea getting from google database*/
  /* $('#frmGoogleDB').val(1); */

  marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
  }));
  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
  marker.setVisible(true);

  var address = '';
  if (place.address_components) {
    address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
    ].join(' ');
  }

  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
function setupClickListener(id, types) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    autocomplete.setTypes(types);
  });
}

setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDem6tqqXGpyvFNmgIdVIsmg3VlPZxAwe8&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

The problem is the above code is- it show the result with state and country like **Eden Garden, Kolkata, West Bengal, India**. My requirement is to show the result as **Eden Garden, Kolkata** and fill the input field as **Eden Garden, Kolkata**.

2- Calculate the Distance between this autocomplete place and a seller's lat-long . below is the code - $google_landmark refer to autocomplete google places

```
$api_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($google_landmark).'&sensor=false';

            $geo = file_get_contents($api_url);
            $geoDecoded = json_decode($geo, true);      
            if ($geoDecoded['status'] = 'OK') {
                $latitude = $geoDecoded['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                $longitude = $geoDecoded['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
                //echo $latitude.'-'.$longitude.'<br/>';
                $distance = $this->getMaxDistance($latitude, $longitude, $arrVenLatLng);     
            }

public function getMaxDistance($CustLatitude, $CustLongitude, $arrVenLatLng){
     $arrDistance = array();

     for($i=0; $i<count($arrVenLatLng); $i++){
        $geoDist = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='.$CustLatitude.','.$CustLongitude.'&destinations='.$arrVenLatLng[$i]['lat'].','.$arrVenLatLng[$i]['long'].'&key=AIzaSyBV8Dbe9bMAK35VmLUSN30xXivN7ICVvsg');
        $geoDist = json_decode($geoDist, true);     

        if($geoDist['status'] = 'OK'){
            $arrDistance[] = $geoDist['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']/1000;
        }
     }

     return ceil(max($arrDistance));
}
```

The google places show a result **Eden Garden, Kolkata, West Bengal, India**

but the

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Eden Garden, Kolkata, West Bengal, India&sensor=false';
```

not return a result. please suggest what is the problem with my code or logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I have read from your code above, you have a fixed position:

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 28.6315, lng: 77.2167},
  zoom: 13
});

It might be the problem, that your lat and lng cannot get updated.

-Paul

Comment: we are not saving the lat-lng of place. we just save the places as string in database and then get lat-long on run time through https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($google_landmark).'&sensor=false this API .

Answer (score 0):

Google geocoder API works effective only when it is given exact addresses. The problem with your second call is even though **Eden Garderns, Kolakata, West Bengal, India** is from an auto complete value provided by the Google places API, this **place** actually has an adress as **Churchgate, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400020, India**. If you pass this actual address to the Google geocoder API then you will be able to retrieve the lat/long.Instead of directly taking the auto fill value get the **address** from the place selected. (Google place API has a place detail request and you can get complete address through that).